# How to extract zip file and keep original in linux?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, zip, gzip

I want to unzip a zip archive on server and keep original zip file with is as well.

When I use unzip `myFile.zip` command it only adds extracted `myFile` but removes the original `myFile.zip` file.
So what command should I use to keep original file with extracted file?

Comment: Are you sure? `unzip` doesn't remove the original (`gzip`/`gunzip` does, though).

Comment: @choroba I have to extract the file in other directory. So i used this command  `unzip  myFile.zip  -d  home/ubuntu/directoryPath` . But it only puts myFile not myFile.zip in directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can duplicate the file using the cp command and then you have two versions – one to keep and one to unzip or modify in other ways.

Comment: What if i have to extract the file in other directory.

Comment: Yes I am doing the same but it removes the `zip` archive but only adds extracted file.

Comment: Something along the lines of `cp myFile.zip /home/ubuntu/directoryPath/` then `unzip myFile.zip -d /home/ubuntu/directoryPath/` should work

Comment: Thanks for you solution.

Answer (score 12):

`unzip` doesn't copy the archive, it only extracts files from it. To copy the archive to a directory, use `cp`:

```
unzip myFile.zip -d home/ubuntu/directoryPath
cp myFile.zip home/ubuntu/directoryPath
```

The original `myFile.zip` isn't removed, it still exists in the location you extracted the files from.

Comment: Anyone else finding this later, this is the correct solution, the file isn't deleted automatically, you'll have both the file and extracted contents if you just use `unzip <file>`